# Tables cannot be created dynamically in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following Model View Control method to create an application.

I'm trying to dynamically create tables upon a page is loaded. Here is the code for that.

In `dashboard.php`

```
<?php
  require_once ("controller/db-config.php"); 
  require_once  ("controller/connectDB.php");
?>
```

In `db-config.php`

```
<?php
    define('DB_NAME', 'learningcamp');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); //Put your MySQL password here
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
?>
```

In `connectDB.php`

```
<?php
    require_once ("controller/db-config.php");     
    require_once ("model/database.php");


    // Create database connection
    $databaseConnection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($databaseConnection->connect_errno)
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . $databaseConnection->connect_error);
    }

    // Create tables if needed.
    prep_DB_content();
?>
```

In `database.php`

```
<?php
    require_once ("controller/db-config.php"); 

    function prep_DB_content (){
        global $databaseConnection;
        create_tables($databaseConnection);
    }

    function create_tables($databaseConnection){    
        $query_fo_pages = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frontoffice (sl INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, field VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(800), flag INT NOT NULL)";
        $databaseConnection->query($query_fo_pages);

    }
?>
```

But somehow the tables are not created when I refresh the page `dashboard.php`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Put this at the top of dashboard.php and refresh the page: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: i assume you actually did put your password there...

Comment: There's no password.

Comment: @Adelphia: Tried the first one, but not showing any errors.

Comment: I think you need a PRIMARY KEY in there

Comment: Is it mandatory to have a primary key for creating a table? It can also not have a primary key if the table don't have too many rows right?

Comment: Can you print `$databaseConnection->error` ?

Comment: No but auto increment needs primary key      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frontoffice 
    (sl INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     field VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(800),
     flag INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sl))`

Comment: @Mihai: You are right. Now the problem is solved.

Comment: @Mihai: ALso is there a way to put the VARCHAR value to MAX without mentioning the limit?

Comment: Mysql AFAIK does not support MAX just put in 255 but in general dont  use more than you need.

Comment: So if the VARCHAR length exceeds 255 characters, what happens?

Comment: You`ll have a message about truncated values and it`s not characters is bytes  I think.

Comment: But in this case, I will have characters more than 255, so which is the best way?

Comment: ITs not characters,byt if you need a lot of characters use TEXT type

Comment: I have a MySQL database that has more than 255 length for the VARCHAR items. MySQL 5.0.3 and later supports very large counts. [65,535 to be exact.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: Mihai: Okay
@McAdam331: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: While you can use an absurdly large amount, it's a good idea not to waste any more space than you need to. I would still keep your count as low as possible.

Comment: So I hope in my case, TEXT would be the perfect one.

Comment: Try it, comment later and let us know. I'm definitely curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you defined an AUTO_INCREMENT column but not a primary key.

If you define any columns as auto increment, you must also make them key. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frontoffice(
    sl INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    field VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(800), 
    flag INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sl))
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa7af)

**EDIT**

To answer your question in the comments, you would not have been required to declare a primary key if you had not used an auto_increment column.

[Fiddle without auto increment and key.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f64f)

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your SQL creation:

```
    $query_fo_pages = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frontoffice (sl INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, field VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(800), flag INT NOT NULL)";
```

Add `PRIMARY KEY` on `auto_increment` column.